# Cannot access a server when tp-link Archer router switches over to backup 4G

Tags: networking, router

I've got a Windows 2012 server connected to a **tp-link Archer MR600** router. In everyday use the Archer has an incoming hard-wired network cable coming from a fibre Internet box elsewhere in the premises (gateway 192.168.1.1). The Archer has its own DHCP for the server, creating its own IP range (gateway 192.168.0.1). When the network cable is connected, everything works well: the server has outgoing Internet, and responds to Web requests. The DMZ is set up on the Archer to point to the server. (Just keeping things simple for now before I fully lock it down.)

The Windows server confirms through ipconfig that its gateway is 192.168.0.1.

If I disconnect the network cable to the Archer to simulate losing the fibre, the 4G seems to successfully kick in. I still have outgoing Internet, and the IP address updates. I have a domain name to the server on the no-ip service, and dynamic update is working: no-ip is showing the new 4G IP address, and checking the DNS for that domain name does return the new 4G IP address.

But I can no longer contact the server from an external machine. A simple test Web page never connects. The Archer advanced config page shows it's connected, using 4G, the DMZ is active still. The reserved internal IP address to the server hasn't changed. I've also tried connecting to the new 4G IP address over my phone on a separate 4G, and it too times-out trying to connect.

Sorry, networking is far from my speciality and I'm a bit lost on what to check next or how to find out where it's failing: the 4G? The Archer? The server?

Comment: You should check whether or not you're behind a CG-NAT when using the mobile service. Almost certainly you are.

Comment: Yep, that seems to be the answer. Thank you! I didn't know that was a thing, but apparently the Three network still offers a workaround, and testing using one of their SIMs worked.

Answer (score 0):

As @ChanganAuto rightfully pointed out that the problem is CG-NAT. Three's mobile network has an APN that isn't behind CG-NAT. When I tested with one of their SIMs using the 3Internet APN, I could connect to the server just fine.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).